# What are the relationship and difference between ambiguous grammars and non-deterministic ones?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, grammars, nondeterminism

Intuitively, I had assumed that ambiguous grammars were roughly the same as non-deterministic grammars.  [According to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_grammar) [Wikipedia however](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unambiguous_grammar), this is false:

> there are non-deterministic unambiguous CFGs

What is the difference between ambiguity and determinism in grammars?  What is an example of a grammar that is non-deterministic but unambiguous?

Comment: First, there is no such thing as a ''deterministic _grammar_''; however, a context-free _language_ $L$ is deterministic if there exists a deterministic pushdown automaton that recognizes it.  The even length palindromes over a binary alphabet form a non-deterministic language $\{ww^R\mid w\in\{a,b\}^\ast\}$ (where $w^R$ denotes the reversal of word $w$), which is unambiguous: there exists an unambiguous _grammar_ for it, e.g. $S\to a\,S\,a\mid b\,S\,b\mid\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Sylvain just to make sure I understand you -- the Wikipedia article is wrong when it says that "In formal grammar theory, the deterministic context-free grammars (DCFGs) are a proper subset of the context-free grammars"?  In that case, maybe I should just delete the OP?

Comment: I think it's an improper use: languages or automata can be deterministic, not grammars.  The correct statement would be "In formal grammar theory, the deterministic context-free languages (DCFL) are a proper subset of the context-free languages (CFL)".

Comment: I hadn't looked at the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_grammar).  They define deterministic CFGs as those for which there exists a DPDA with the same language.  It's a dangerous definition, because it doesn't tell you _how_ to construct this DPDA.  A paragraph later they write nonsense: "DCFGs are of great practical interest, as they can be parsed in linear time and in fact a parser can be automatically generated from the grammar by a parser generator", altough it is *undecidable*, given a CFG, whether its language is a DCFL.

Comment: @Sylvain I know the ambiguity problem is undecidable but I thought it was decidable whether a given CFG is deterministic. There is a description of a "DK-test" in Sipser's introductory book (3rd edition) that a CFG passes iff it is deterministic.

Comment: @sjmc: What Sipser calls DCFG is the class of LR(0) grammars (p. 152 of Sipster's _Introduction to the Theory of Computation_ 3rd Edition).  For such grammars, and more generally LR($k$) grammars for some fixed $k$, you have an effective DPDA construction.

Answer (score 2):

See this related Wikipedia link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unambiguous_grammar#Recognizing_ambiguous_grammars

> The efficiency of context-free grammar parsing is determined by the
>   automaton that accepts it. Deterministic context-free grammars are
>   accepted by deterministic pushdown automata and can be parsed in
>   linear time, for example by the LR parser.[3] This is a subset of the
>   context-free grammars which are accepted by the pushdown automaton and
>   can be parsed in polynomial time, for example by the CYK algorithm.
>   **Unambiguous context-free grammars can be nondeterministic. For example, the language of even-length palindromes on the alphabet of 0
>   and 1 has the unambiguous context-free grammar S → 0S0 | 1S1 | ε. An
>   arbitrary string of this language cannot be parsed without reading all
>   its letters first which means that a pushdown automaton has to try
>   alternative state transitions to accommodate for the different
>   possible lengths of a semi-parsed string.[4]** Nevertheless, removing
>   grammar ambiguity may produce a deterministic context-free grammar and
>   thus allow for more efficient parsing. Compiler generators such as
>   YACC include features for resolving some kinds of ambiguity, such as
>   by using the precedence and associativity constraints.

An ambiguous grammar may be defined as a grammar for which there exists more than one parse tree for some string belonging to the language it generates.

A deterministic grammar may be defined as a grammar for which there exists a deterministic machine model which is capable of recognizing the language it generates.

Assume Grammar 1 generates the same language as Grammar 2.  Assume Grammar 1 is unambiguous and Grammar 2 is ambiguous.  If a deterministic machine model is capable of recognizing the language generated by Grammar 1, then it is also capable of recognizing the language generated by Grammar 2 (by the assumption that they both generate the same language).  Clearly, both are deterministic grammars and yet they differ on the question of ambiguity.

The definition of grammar **ambiguity** addresses the actual syntactical **structure of the grammar** and its relation to parsing, NOT whether an ambiguous grammar could be structured differently so as to generate the same language and yet remove ambiguity.

The definition of grammar **determinism**, however, is not related to the structure of a grammar but rather to the **properties of the language** it generates regarding recognition by an appropriate deterministic machine model.